# Image escapes div with height and css grid

Tags: css

In the following example why does the rectangle not stay in the div?

```css
body
{
  background-color:blue;
}
#div53
{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, grey, white);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#img60
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div53">
    <img id="img60" alt="Thumbnail" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwMCI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI3OTAiIGhlaWdodD0iMzkwIiB4PSI1IiB5PSI1IiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjUiIGZpbGw9InJlZCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=">
</div>
```

I can see that removing the grid makes it work but this is a reduced example.
The width works as expected.

Update: This seems to work in firefox but not in google-chrome.

Comment: I was wrong sorry.

Comment: Although it doesn't seem to be coming out when I click run code snippet.

Comment: Your svg contains hard coded width and height, it's not dynamic. My guess it's not obeying the style size because of that.

Comment: That's why giving example as a snippet is preferrable, so everyone would see the same thing.  Feel free edit your code use "edit the above snippet" link

Answer (score 0):

The div element is forced to have height of 340px and image is set to 100% of height(which is 400 px), this makes the image to overflow the div.

Options are

- remove the heigh of the div
- set height of image to be same as div

```css
body
{
  background-color:blue;
}
#div53
{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, grey, white);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#img60
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div53">
    <img id="img60" alt="Thumbnail" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwMCI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI3OTAiIGhlaWdodD0iMzkwIiB4PSI1IiB5PSI1IiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjUiIGZpbGw9InJlZCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=">
</div>
```

Comment: The image width isn't set to 100% its max-width is 100%

Comment: Apologies, what i meant was image height not width, image renders by default with height of 100% unless specified otherwise. You can try to set image width to 340px which will render the image within the div. I have updated my snippet on the same.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem (or answer the question).

Answer (score 0):

The following solves my problem, but doesn't answer my question.

```css
body
{
  background-color:blue;
}
#div53
{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, grey, white);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0,1fr);
}

#img60
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div53">
    <img id="img60" alt="Thumbnail" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQwMCI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI3OTAiIGhlaWdodD0iMzkwIiB4PSI1IiB5PSI1IiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjUiIGZpbGw9InJlZCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=">
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What isn't clear. What I did above causes the rectangle to stay in the div (i.e solves my problem). However, it doesn't answer my question "why wasn't the previous css enough?"